# How to find table grid lines in PDF files?

Tags: python, pdf-extraction, python-camelot, pymupdf, pdfplumber

To more accurately extract table-like data embedded within table cells, I would like to be able to identify table cell boundaries in PDFs like this:

[image: pdf table example]

I have tried extracting such tables using Camelot, pdfplumber, and PyMuPDF, with varying degrees of success. But due to the inconsistency of the PDFs we receive, I'm not able to reliably get accurate results, even when specifying the table bounds.

I find that the results are better if I extract each table cell individually, by specifying the cell boundaries explicitly. I have tested this by manually entering the boundaries, which I get using Camelot's visual debugging tool.

My challenge is how to identify table cell boundaries programmatically, since the table may start anywhere on the page, and the cells are of variable vertical height.

It seems to me that one could do this by finding the coordinates of the row separator lines, which are so obvious visually to a human. But I have not figured out how to find these lines using python tools. Is this possible, or are there other/better ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Are your PDFs scans or images, or do they contain actual highlightable text? If the former, an OCR engine and some machine learning may be required.

Comment: The PDFs contain embedded text, which is extracted by any of the tools I mentioned. My challenge is making sense of the text, due to the variability of the source material and the capabilities of the various tools.

Comment: Have you tried finding vertical and horizontal edges using `pdfplumber`? The default `page.debug_table_finder()` gives you an option to list edges.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ghost. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had a similar use case where I needed to figure out the boundaries via code itself. For your use case, there are two options:

1. If you want to identify the boundary of the entire table, you can do the following:

```py
import pdfplumber
pdf = pdfplumber.open('file_name.pdf')
p0 = pdf.pages[req_page] # go to the required page

tables = p0.debug_tablefinder() # list of tables which pdfplumber identifies
req_table = tables.tables[i] # Suppose you want to use ith table

req_table.bbox # gives you the bounding box of the table (coordinates)
```

2. You want to visit each cell in the table and extract, say words, from them:

```py
import pdfplumber
pdf = pdfplumber.open('file_name.pdf')
p0 = pdf.pages[req_page] # go to the required page

tables = p0.debug_tablefinder() # list of tables which pdfplumber identifies
req_table = tables.tables[i] # Suppose you want to use ith table

cells = req_table.cells # gives list of all cells in that table

for cell in cells[i:j]: # iterating through the required cells
    p0.crop(cell).extract_words() # extract the words
```